# Executing an asynchronous method from the dispose event

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xunit.net

In my unit/integration tests (xUnit.net) I need to run some cleanup code that will remove some resources that may have been created.  I'd like to do this only once.  **DeleteBucket** is an async method.  What are my options?  Is there a "pre-dispose" event?

```
public void Dispose()
{
    var api = new AwsApi(creds, stdout);
    var success = await api.DeleteBucket(bucket, new CancellationTokenSource());
}
```

Comment: Since this is a test, and not production code, is there a reason not to block on the async task and wait for the result?

Comment: A bigger issue here is the allocation in your `Dispose()` method. Hopefully this entire class is unit-test-only. Even there, I would seriously reconsider this design. It would be much better if a) the `AwsApi` instance were created somewhere else, and b) the asynchronous cleanup can be done outside of the synchronous call to `Dispose()`. Lacking a good code example, not much else can be said. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: blocking the asycn task did the trick

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit: That's fine for unit test code. If you ever need asynchronous disposal in production code, I describe a couple of approaches [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/03/async-oop-6-disposal.html).